# Reading a csv file of city distance in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have a file like this as csv

[image]

Now i want this file to create facts such as this in prolog as

```
distance(A,E,3)
distance(A,G,5)
and so on.
```

As per the other answers I have tried
csv_read_file("test.csv", Rows, [functor(citydist), arity(5)]),   maplist(assert, Rows), print(Rows).

but this is returning just a row wise data. How to read it as an adjacency graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the CSV looks something like :

```
"Distance","E","G","C","B"
"A","3","5","7","3"
"B","4","5","6","0"
"C","4","1","0","6"
"D","5","8","3","6"
```

```
:- [library(csv)] .
:- [library(lists)] .

%! distance(CITY_A,CITY_B,DISTANCE)
%
% dynamic facts asserted based upon csv file .

:- dynamic distance/3 .

:- op(1,'xfy','csv_') .


%! csv(FILE0)
%
% read the CSV file `FILE0` and add facts to the database .

csv(FILE0)
:-
(start) csv_ (FILE0)
.

(start) csv_ (FILE0)
:-
csv:csv_read_file(FILE0,[HEADER|ROWss]) ,
row__to__list(HEADER,HEADERs) ,
(loop) csv_ (HEADERs,ROWss) 
.

(loop) csv_ (_HEADERs,[]) 
:-
true
.

(loop) csv_ (HEADERs,[ROW|ROWss]) 
:-
row__to__list(ROW,ROWs) ,
lists:nth1(1,ROWs,CITY_A) ,
QUERY_A=(lists:nth1(NTH,ROWs,DISTANCE)) ,
QUERY_B=(NTH > 1) ,
QUERY_C=(lists:nth1(NTH,HEADERs,CITY_B)) ,
QUERY=(QUERY_A,QUERY_B,QUERY_C) ,
ASSERT=assertz(distance(CITY_A,CITY_B,DISTANCE)) ,
forall(QUERY,ASSERT) ,
(loop) csv_ (HEADERs,ROWss) 
.

row__to__list(ROW,ROWs)
:-
ROW=..[_|ROWs]
.

/*
?- csv('data/distances.csv').
true ;
false.

?- listing(distance).

distance('A', 'E', 3).
distance('A', 'G', 5).
distance('A', 'C', 7).
distance('A', 'B', 3).
distance('B', 'E', 4).
distance('B', 'G', 5).
distance('B', 'C', 6).
distance('B', 'B', 0).
distance('C', 'E', 4).
distance('C', 'G', 1).
distance('C', 'C', 0).
distance('C', 'B', 6).
distance('D', 'E', 5).
distance('D', 'G', 8).
distance('D', 'C', 3).
distance('D', 'B', 6).

?-
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Reminder: Capital valued entities are logic variables, so your facts should have lower case letters a, b, c, etc.

Supposing you know what are your nodes, once the distances have been entered into Prolog, here's how to find the adjacent nodes for a given Node:

```
adjacencies(Node, Adjacencies) :-
    findall(Adj, distance(Node, Adj, _), Adjacencies).
```

So with some distance facts like in your illustration,

```
?- adjacencies(a, L).
L = [e,g,c,b]
```

Does this anwser your question ?

Comment: Can you define what is your goal, before talking of search strategy ?

Comment: You asked for an adjacency graph, did you get what you asked for ?

Comment: There are already several questions and answers on this topic on stackoverflow. Find and read them. If you have specific questions on a (small) task, then ask ! To have your homework done for you, will not help your understanding on Prolog.

Comment: The only answers on SO are about reading csv line by line, I can't find this row,column pair csv read anywhere. and about the problem statement, You asked for the goal thats why I mentioned it to maybe give you some context.